# How to compare a 2-D array and 1-D Array and to Store common Data in Another Array in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have 2 Arrays and one is 2 dimensional and another is 1 dimensional. I need to compare both and need to store there common data in another array. I tried the below approach:-

```
tw.local.listtodisplayNW = new tw.object.listOf.listtodisplayNWBO();
//if(tw.local.SQLResults[0].rows.listLength >
//    tw.local.virtualServers.listLength)
var k=0;
for (var i=0;i<tw.local.SQLResults[0].rows.listLength;i++)  
{
log.info("Inside SQLResults loop - For RuntimeID: " 
+tw.local.SQLResults[0].rows[i].data[3]);
for(var j=0;j<tw.local.virtualServers.listLength;j++)
{
    log.info("Inside API loop - For RuntimeID: " 
+tw.local.virtualServers[j].runtimeid);
    if(tw.local.SQLResults[0].rows[i].data[3] == 
tw.local.virtualServers[j].runtimeid)
    {
        tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k] = new tw.object.listtodisplayNWBO();
        tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].vsysName = 
tw.local.virtualServers[j].virtualSystemName;
        tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].vsysID = 
tw.local.virtualServers[j].virtualSystemId;
        tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].serverName = 
tw.local.virtualServers[j].serverName;
        tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].serverID = 
tw.local.virtualServers[j].serverId;
        tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].runtimeID = 
tw.local.virtualServers[j].runtimeid;
        //tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].IPAddress = 
tw.local.virtualServers[j].nics[j].ipAddress;
        log.info("VsysName: 
"+tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].vsysName+"RuntimeID: 
"+tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].runtimeID);
        //tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k] = new 
tw.object.listtodisplayNWBO();
        tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].currentSpeed = 
tw.local.SQLResults[0].rows[i].data[5];
        log.info("VsysName: 
"+tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].vsysName+"RuntimeID: 
"+tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].runtimeID+"CurrentSpeed: 
"+tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].currentSpeed);
        if(tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].currentSpeed != "100 Mbps")
        {
           tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].desiredSpeed = "100 Mbps";
         }
        else
        {
           tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].desiredSpeed = "1 Gbps";
        }
        log.info("DesiredSpeed: 
 "+tw.local.listtodisplayNW[k].desiredSpeed);
        k++; 
     }

 }
 log.info("Length of 
 listtodisplayNW"+tw.local.listtodisplayNW.listLength);
 }
```

In above code SQLResults is a 2-d array and virtualServers is a 1-D array.
I need to compare both these array and common data need to be store in another array. Here performance is not good. Is there any other way to do this efficiently. Please make a needful favour and Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the two arrays and also what common data has to be moved to another array?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Here SQLResults[0].rows[i].data[3]  is an array of 2-D. Here we are matching 4th element of each row of SQLResults[0] with every element of virtualServers[] array. If matched then we will be placing that in another array. Above code is also performing the task but performance hit is the main problem.

Comment: can you share examples of these two arrays and what kind of matching will be there?

Comment: if(tw.local.SQLResults[0].rows[i].data[3] ==tw.local.virtualServers[j].runtimeid)  is the matching condition that is value of the elements..

Comment: So, you are basically doing a join between two large arrays and then storing the results in an another array?

Comment: I am comparing both the arrays i.e. 4th element of every row( e.g. SQLResults[0].rows[i].data[3]  here data[3] represent 4th column and row[i] represents i th row) of SQLResults[0] with every element of virtualServers array. If it matches then store that in another array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming integer data, the following example works on the theme of array implementation of set intersection, which will take care of performance.

1. Convert 2D array to 1D.

   ```
   var 2DtoIDArray =  2DArray.join().split(",");
   ```
2. Create an array named **marker** whose purpose is to serve as a lookup that element.
   This needs to be done as follows.

   Iterate through the smaller array, say **1DArray** and keep setting **marker** as follows throughout iteration.

   ```
   marker[1DArray[counter]]='S1';
   ```

   Now iterate through 2Dto1DArray array(you may use nested loop iteration if you dont want to convert it to 1 dimesnional) and for each element
   of this array check if its marked as 'S1' in the **marker** lookup array.
   If yes, keep adding the elements in the **commonElementsArray**.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this simple approach

1. Since the matching condition is only one between the two large arrays, create two maps (one for each array) to map each record against that attribute which is to be matched

For `SQLResults`

```
var map1 = {};
tw.local.SQLResults[0].rows.each( function(row){
  map1[ row.data[3] ] = row;
});
```

and similarly for virtual servers

```
var map2 = {};
tw.local.virtualServers.each( function(vs){
  map2[ vs.runtimeid ] = vs;
});
```

2. Now iterate these two maps wrt to their keys and set the values in new array

new array being tw.local.listtodisplayNW

```
tw.local.listtodisplayNW = [];
Object.keys( map1 ).forEach( function( key ){
   if( map2[ key ] )
   {
     //set the values in tw.local.listtodisplayNW 
   }
})
```

Complexity of the approach is simply O(n) since there is no nested loops.

Comment: for virtual server code that you shared above, I think there we need to have var map2 instead of map1. Am I correct..?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will fix that typo